# Setup a server with Java on a Debian server

Tags: java, server, debian

I need to setup a java server on an existing Debian server. The fact is that it's not just a "webservice", I need it to run constantly and to listen to requests on a specific port and respond to it. It's a kind of bot doing its work but also listening for requests in order to interact and respond to those.

The fact is that I know how to run a Java process running constantly, and I don't know very much on how to set it all up.

I don't know if I'm clear, so don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you run a Spring Boot application inside a Docker container?

Check out this article :
https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/